# How to get data from this "list" looking thing in python 2.7

Tags: python, list

I'm working on a project that implements stock data, (it's in python 2.7). The module i'm using (yahoo finance https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance) will return historical data in this format:

```
print yahoo.get_historical('2014-04-25', '2014-04-29')
[{u'Volume': u'28720000', u'Symbol': u'YHOO', u'Adj_Close': u'35.83', u'High': u'35.89', u'Low': u'34.12', u'Date': u'2014-04-29', u'Close': u'35.83', u'Open': u'34.37'}, {u'Volume': u'30422000', u'Symbol': u'YHOO', u'Adj_Close': u'33.99', u'High': u'35.00', u'Low': u'33.65', u'Date': u'2014-04-28', u'Close': u'33.99', u'Open': u'34.67'}, {u'Volume': u'19391100', u'Symbol': u'YHOO', u'Adj_Close': u'34.48', u'High': u'35.10', u'Low': u'34.29', u'Date': u'2014-04-25', u'Close': u'34.48', u'Open': u'35.03'}]
```

Is there any way to parse this data like a list? I don't recognize the formatting it's in. Is there any simple way i could separate the high for the day? I thought about just making it a string and using something like

```
string = yahoo.get_historical('2014-04-25', '2014-04-29')
string[13] + string[14] + string[15] ... + string[21] = Volume
```

but I know there must be a better way to do this. Hopefully it's something simple that I'm missing.

Comment: It is a list of [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a list of dictionaries, three items in a list. Easier to see if using the `pprint.pprint()` module function:

```
[{u'Adj_Close': u'35.83',
  u'Close': u'35.83',
  u'Date': u'2014-04-29',
  u'High': u'35.89',
  u'Low': u'34.12',
  u'Open': u'34.37',
  u'Symbol': u'YHOO',
  u'Volume': u'28720000'},

 {u'Adj_Close': u'33.99',
  u'Close': u'33.99',
  u'Date': u'2014-04-28',
  u'High': u'35.00',
  u'Low': u'33.65',
  u'Open': u'34.67',
  u'Symbol': u'YHOO',
  u'Volume': u'30422000'},

 {u'Adj_Close': u'34.48',
  u'Close': u'34.48',
  u'Date': u'2014-04-25',
  u'High': u'35.10',
  u'Low': u'34.29',
  u'Open': u'35.03',
  u'Symbol': u'YHOO',
  u'Volume': u'19391100'}]
```

You can read them like:

```
readings = yahoo.get_historical('2014-04-25', '2014-04-29')
for reading in readings:
    print reading['Volume']
```

The high for the day could be:

```
high_reading = max(readings, key=lambda reading: float(reading['High']))
```

(which is the `max()` function which returns the biggest thing in a sequence, provided with a custom function to say what it should look at when comparing the items).

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use a syntax like: `for dayData in dict` to separate the values for each day and do the processing in the for loop with something like dayDict['Volume']. Then you can just add any details to a master array outside the loop for further processing or analytics later in the code.